# Is it right way to place applications constant as shown in my code example?

Tags: java, enums, constants

```
public enum AppConst{
    WIDTH (1280),
    HEIGHT (800);

    private final int value;

    AppConst(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    private int get() { return value; }
}
```

**VS.**

```
public class AppConst{
    public static final int WIDTH = 1280;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 800;
}
```

I read that `enums` are better to use for storing constant values. Is it a good way to store them as I showed or did I misunderstood something?

**EDIT**.
I thought that it could be better to put all such values in one place, for we could easily modify them if we need to. Am I wrong with that?

**EDIT2.**
AppConst is intended to be a place, where I will store all values, which shouldn't be "magic numbers". Such as windows coordinates and etc. I planned that there could be some fields as DAYS_IN_WEEK = 7, MAX_smth = ..., ... , ... .

Comment: For real *value*-constant's like your's, this is a little overkill. Use enums for *enumerated*-types, like states or something.

Comment: Enums provide more useful methods... Enum javadoc - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html

Comment: IMHO I would prefer to use the `enum` approach. If you will go for the class solution, at least make it `final` (no class could inherit it) and make the constructor `private` (no need to create an instance of the class).

Answer (score 3):

The main benefit of using `Enums` instead of `static final` variables is when dealing with restrictions on method parameters for safety needs. Here's an example:

```
public void myMethod(int width, int height){}
```

VS

```
public void myMethod(AppConst width, AppConst height){}
```

The second restricts the acceptable `int` values, in your case:  800 and 1280.

So, according to your needs, enums can be safer than static constants.

Besides, as you don't bring behaviour into your enum, you can shortly write:

```
public enum AppConst{
    WIDTH (1280),
    HEIGHT (800);
}
```

Comment: In this case, I suspect AppConst will becomre of a a "sink" for const variables, of unrelated types, so I wonder if there would be any method that gets an AppConst as a parameter... but of course that's hard to say without knowing te whole context...

Comment: @phtrivier Indeed, without context, hard to judge the consistency of chosen way.

Answer (score 2):

Enums are meant to represent enumerated types ; that is, a type of data that simply consists of a finite, known set of values. Adding data to an enum is interesting if want to add more than one "bit" of information :

public enum Gender
      MALE("male", "man", "Mr"),
      FEMALE("female", "woman", "Ms");

```
  private String genderName;
  private String genderPerson;
  private String genderTitle;

  ....
```

}

Typically, there are used to have one variable that represent an object, and switch on its value.

I think in your case, you simply want to have two well-know values for integers, so I would go for the static final int.

Note, that as pointed out by @PremGenEditor, you might run into the case where your WIDTH and HEIGHT change, so they might end up being just another property of some object ; and they would naturally be an int.

Answer (score 2):

Usually enumerations are used to contain set of values for the same kind of entity. While this might still be kind of appropriate in your case with only WIDTH and HEIGHT, it will not be anymore if you need to add a new application constant for, let's say, the background color.

The name of the class AppConst makes me think of something generic. I see two cases here:

1. If you are actually planning to use this in the future for other additional
   constants that have nothing to do with dimensions, I would
   definitely choose for the static option.
2. If you are planning to use this only for those two constants only, I
   would then use a name different from AppConst, which give the idea
   we are talking about dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

For real *value*-constant's like your's, this is a little overkill. Use enums for *enumerated*-types, like states or something.

Back in the day, you might have done something like this:

```
public static final int STATUS_OKAY = 0;
public static final int STATUS_ERROR = 1;
public static final int STATUS_WARNING = 3;

public static final int SOMETHINGELSE = 0;

// ...

if (getStatus() == STATUS_OKAY){
    // Do something...
}
if (getStatus() == 4) // This is NEVER true! Still it's allowed
```

But this is not type-save. You can also compare it to a value that is not even there (let's say `4`). With enums, you don't have that and your code is more readable:

```
public enum Status{
    OKAY, WARNING, ERROR
}

if (getStatus() == Status.OKAY){
    // Do Something
}
if (getStatus() == Status.DOESNTEXIST) // Compile-time error.
```

The intend becomes more clear, you get better code and you have compile-time security for *enumerated*-constants.

---

In your example, `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` are just constant *values*, you can store them as constant fields.

Answer (score 0):

Enums in Java are type-safe and has there own name-space. It means your enum will have a type for example "AppConst" in below example and you can not assign any value other than specified in Enum Constants.

```
public enum AppConst { WIDTH (1280), HEIGHT (800);}
AppConst height = AppConst.HEIGHT;
height = 1; /*compilation error*/
```

Enum in Java are reference type like class or interface and you can define constructor, methods and variables inside java Enum which makes it more powerful than Enum in C and C++ languages.

Enum in java can be used as an argument on switch statment and with "case:" like int or char primitive type. This feature of java enum makes them very useful for switch operations.

Since constants defined inside Enum in Java are final you can safely compare them using "==" equality operator as shown below:

```
AppConst height = AppConst.HEIGHT;
if (height == AppConst.HEIGHT){
  System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

But comparing objects using == operator is not recommended, always use equals() method or compareTo() method to compare Objects.

Enum in Java can implement the interface and override any method like normal class It’s also worth noting that Enum in java implicitly implement both Serializable and Comparable interface.

You can define abstract methods inside Enum in Java and can also provide different implementation for different instances of enum in java.

Enum has its own name-space. Adding new constants on Enum in Java is easy and you can add new constants without breaking existing code.